# Set project root directory path in .properties file

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I have a spring boot project that has a custom file at the project root level. I need to set a configuration to point to the root directory, without which the app won't start.
This is required by an external dependency that I need to use.

I can easily do this in build.gradle at the bootrun task as follows

```
bootRun {
    jvmArgs = [
            "-Dapp.config=${projectDir}"
    ]
}
```

But how can I set app.config to point to the project root in application.properties file.

By setting it in bootrun, I can successfully start the application but I cannot run controller tests as this value is required at start up.

Comment: The classloader will generally load the resource  fine with the classpath url path of `"/config.properties"`

Comment: Assuming you're running from a jar, there IS NO project directory. You can use `/` as the root of the `src/main/resources`, which is where people usually put stuff that end up at the root of the jar.